# How to create a new word document from document template in Sharepoint

Tags: microsoft-word, sharepoint, microsoft-word-2010

Is there an easier way to create a new document (in Word 2010) from a document template in Sharepoint?

Right now, this is how I do it:

1. Go to Sharepoint site and edit .dotx in Word.
2. Click "File" from the ribbon and choose "New".
3. From the "Available templates" section, click "New from existing".
4. From the "New from Existing Document" dialog, choose the Sharepoint document, and click "Create New".
5. Once the new document opens, click "File" from the ribbon again, and choose "Save as". The document will be saved as .docx

Comment: even this doesn't seem to work now, at least I can't see "new from existing"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [Create a site Content Type](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/create-a-site-content-type-HA010097493.aspx). This allows you to have your predefined templates built in to SharePoint Document Libraries and then use the New button in a given document library to select from the available templates. This is much better then your current approach.

Updated link: [Create or Customize a Site Content Type](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-or-customize-a-site-content-type-27eb6551-9867-4201-a819-620c5658a60f)

Comment: I tried this, but my new template doesn't appear when I click the arrow on the new button.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Aha!  I had to add the content type to the library.  Thanks.

Comment: this link is dead