# How can I create a new Word 365 from a template stored in SharePoint?

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, sharepoint, sharepoint-server-2019

Pre-Sharepoint things were easy. You double-clicked a .dot file and automatically got a new document from this template. Or you could add a folder to Word and templates in that folder would be available.

Fast-forward to Office365 and Sharepoint 2019 and I can't see how to do either. We have a bunch of .dotx files in SharePoint but if I click one in the browser, it just opens the file in Word in protected mode. And I can't see any way to add a SP folder as a set of commonly used templates.

(I found an [old question](https://superuser.com/questions/199712/how-to-create-a-new-word-document-from-document-template-in-sharepoint) that's basically the same *but* it refers to much older versions of Word/Sharepoint (and the answer points to a broken link) - I think things are quite different in modern versions especially SP)

Comment: I am not answering as such because I do not have SharePoint. Can you copy the sharepoint templates folder to a local or network location and set it as your Workgroup templates location? This is a bug in SharePoint (IMO) in that the action of creating a new document from a template is lost. See also https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/733217/autotext-being-stripped-in-dotx-templates-on-share.html which discusses loss of ability to use building blocks in templates on SharePoint.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon probably (if I can see _where_ to set workgroup templates as that seems to have moved too) but then if the templates get updated, I will be out of date.

Comment: Here is my writing on workgroup templates settings. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Workgroup http://www.addbalance.com/word/workgrouptemplates.htm You are correct that you will be out of date. Calendar updating on a monthly basis or as necessary. When they are on a network folder, such updating can be made a part of the login. I suppose you could incorporate it into a Windows startup script if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [updated link on the Custom Content Type](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-or-customize-a-site-content-type-27eb6551-9867-4201-a819-620c5658a60f).  Since I do not have SharePoint, I have no idea whether or not this addresses your problem.

Otherwise, if you can copy the templates from SharePoint to a local or network drive set as your [WorkGroup Templates folder](http://www.addbalance.com/word/workgrouptemplates.htm), they will work normally. You should set up a way to update these on a regular basis, perhaps a startup script for your computer using XCOPY.